# Flutter- How to handle deeplinking with another screen

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, deep-linking

I have implemented deep linking in my app. I added intent filter in my manifest file, and the deep linking is working. But it open on the start page.
I want the page open on another page which contains ids.

```
Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {
      if (dynamicLinkData != null) {
        // Extract the deep link URL from the PendingDynamicLinkData
        Uri deepLink = dynamicLinkData.link;

        // Extract the query parameters from the deep link URL
        String? name = deepLink.queryParameters['name'];
        String? product = deepLink.queryParameters['product'];

        // Provide default values for the query parameters if they are null
        name ??= 'Default Name';
        product ??= 'Default Product';

        // Navigate to the MenuDetailPage with the extracted parameters
        Get.to(() => MenuDetailPage(name: name!, product: product!));
      }
    }).onError((error) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(error.message);
      }
    });
  }
```

My share button code-

```
IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Construct the Firebase deep link URL
                          String firebaseUrl = 'https://dummydata.page.link/menudetail';
                        // Call the share method to share the deep link
                          String sharedUrl = '$firebaseUrl?name=${Uri.encodeComponent(widget.name)}&product=${Uri.encodeComponent(widget.product)}';
                          Share.share(sharedUrl);
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.share, color: kwhite, size: 30.r,),
```

Comment: In onInitState method of your MenuDetailPage, you need to write code to move to whichever screen you want and also you can pass whichever parameters you want.

Comment: I added the above code in MenuDetailPage initState method, but it still gives start page